# Db query builder use relationship

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, foreign-keys

i have 1 to many relationships. organization with booking. on the booking table foreign key organization_id. organizations table foreign key user_id. user table i have column name|company_account|phone_no..

### organization Table

```
id|user_id|....
```

### controller Query

```
$bookings = DB::table('bookings')
                    ->select([
                        'organization_id', 
                        DB::raw('CAST(created_at AS DATE) as day'),
                        DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN payment_gateway = 'LocalBook' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bookings_localbook_per_day"),
                        DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN payment_gateway = 'LocalBook' THEN commision_i_get ELSE 0 END) AS commision_localbook_per_day"),
                        DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN payment_gateway = 'selfBook' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bookings_selfbook_per_day"),
                        DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN payment_gateway = 'selfBook' THEN commision_i_get ELSE 0 END) AS commision_selfbook_per_day"),

                        DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN payment_gateway = 'paypal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bookings_international_per_day"),
                        DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN payment_gateway = 'paypal' THEN commision_i_get ELSE 0 END) AS commision_international_per_day"),
                        DB::raw('SUM(commision_i_get) AS total_comission_per_day'),
                    ])
                    ->where('pay', '>', 0)
                    ->groupBy(['organization_id', DB::raw('CAST(created_at AS DATE)')])
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray();
```

### what i want here is

inside object instead of organization_id i need oranization.user.name, organization.user.account... using relationship ?? how can i achieve this

Comment: Join `Organization` table into your query using proper joining condition. `$bookings = DB::table('bookings')->join('organization', 'organization.id', '=', 'bookings.organization_id')->select(...`. Do not forget to alter grouping expression.

Comment: Bookings->organizations->users and can you edit me all code please !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try join these 3 tables
Try

```
DB::table('bookings')
    ->join('organizations','organizations.id','=','bookings.organization_id')
    ->join('user','user.id','=','organizations.user_id')
    ->select([
                       'user.account',
                       'user.name',
                        ....])
```

Good practice is you should put the table name before each column, like user.name instead of name only.
Hope it help!